# Type Page1 not found in xmlns

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I try to implement shell page nevertheless when trying to compile i get following error in MasterDetailShell.xaml. I assume something is wrong within the lines regardless path.

```
ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"
```

**Error:**

```
Type Page1 not found in xmlns   MobileAppXamarinForms
```

This is my code:

**App.cs:**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new MasterDetailShell();
        }
}
```

**MasterDetailShell.cs**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MasterDetailShell : Shell
{
     public MasterDetailShell()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }
}
```

**MasterDetailShell.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MobileAppXamarinForms.Views.MasterDetailShell.MasterDetailShell">

    <FlyoutItem Title="MyTabbApp"
                Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"
                FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent Title="Bears" Icon="" IsTabStop="True" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"></ShellContent>
        <ShellContent Title="Bears" Icon="" IsTabStop="True" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}"></ShellContent>
    </FlyoutItem>

    <ShellContent Title="About" Icon="" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}"></ShellContent>
</Shell>
```

Files location:

[image]

Comment: your xaml needs to define `xmlns:local`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the `local` [namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/namespaces) without ever declaring it

```
xmlns:local="using:ThisIsTheNamespaceForPage1"
```

to determine which namespace to use, open `Page.xaml.cs` and look at its `namespace` declaration

Comment: Great that worked ! Can you tell me what is the diffrence between Shell and MasterDetail? To me it's the same..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it has been fixed just  correct the namespace of an necessary  class or add an necessary class

```
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DiplayAnimalCollection"
```

Using correct place

```
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DiplayAnimalCollection.Views"
```